# move to a subsequent column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a calculation where I'm comparing a cell on a before sheet to the same cell on an after sheet. if before is less than after, I'm subtracting one from the other and storing those results in a summary page. 
 I need to do this for each column of the worksheet though and am having a tough time figuring out how to get the calculation performed in the subsequent columns. there is a different category for columns Y through BM.   here is my code so far that works fine for column y and keeping the running total in column a of the summary sheet. 
 can anyone help me to set a column range and move it forward? thank you

```
 Sub TryAgain3()
'evaluates differences in column y (appraisal) in before to column y in after.  if before is less than after (we underdisclosed) then it calculates the difference and sticks it in summary
Dim A() As Integer '~ I will put the result in this column, A
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = Range("y3").End(xlDown).Row 
ReDim A(lastrow)
For i = 1 To lastrow
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Before").Cells(i + 1, 25).Value < ThisWorkbook.Sheets("After").Cells(i + 1, 25) Then
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("summary").Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Before").Cells(i + 1, 25).Value - ThisWorkbook.Sheets("After").Cells(i + 1, 25).Value
    End If

Next I

Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Put another loop outside the current to loop through the column numbers, then replace the `25` that refer to the `Y` column with the variable from the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Scott Craner said in a comment, just add another loop, outside the current one, which loops through the columns.

```
Sub TryAgain3()
    'evaluates differences in column y (appraisal) in before to column y in after.  if before is less than after (we underdisclosed) then it calculates the difference and sticks it in summary
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim lastrow As Integer
    lastrow = Range("y3").End(xlDown).Row 
    For j = 25 To 65  ' columns Y to BM
        For i = 1 To lastrow
            If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Before").Cells(i + 1, j).Value < ThisWorkbook.Sheets("After").Cells(i + 1, j) Then
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("summary").Cells(i + 1, j - 24).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Before").Cells(i + 1, j).Value - ThisWorkbook.Sheets("After").Cells(i + 1, j).Value
            End If
        Next I
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: that's it!  thank you both, I couldn't get it to work quite right and kept getting errors.  Thank you both very much for your help!

Comment: @Pauliec - I noticed your original code had an extra `Next` than it should have had, so I assumed you must have been trying **something** like what we suggested.